# discum click button in dm's

Tags: python, discum

I'm trying to do autoclick on button in DM's using discum.
My actual code:

```
import discum
bot = discum.Client(token='token')
from discum.utils.button import Buttoner

@bot.gateway.command
def message_data(resp):
    if resp.event.message:
        m = resp.parsed.auto() 
        channelID = m['channel_id']
        messageID = m['id']
        message = bot.getMessage(channelID, messageID)
        data = message.json()[0]
        buts = Buttoner(data["components"])
        bot.click(
            data["author"]["id"],
            channelID=data["channel_id"],
            messageID=data["id"],
            messageFlags=data["flags"],
            data=buts.getButton("First"),
        )

bot.gateway.run()
```

It should work but... Nope. Maybe I'm stupid, if you can - please help me!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Buttoner** I don't think you should be converting your data variable to json, could be what is causing your issue, try checking your terminal for an actual error message -> which would help you in identifying the issue.
Try passing your params to buttoner using your default message object without any conversions as so:

```
buts = Buttoner(m["components"])
bot.click(
    m["author"]["id"],
    channelID=m["channel_id"],
    guildID = m['guild_id'] if 'guild_id' in m else None,
    messageID=m["id"],
    messageFlags=m["flags"],
    data=buts.getButton(row=0, column=0),
    sessionID=ses,
)
```

**Additionally** note that Discord button events now require a *sessionID* as well to be passed (to *Buttoner*).
You **cannot** send click events without a session ID (*funnily enough it is not currently checked by Discord so it doesn't need to be valid at all*).
The last parameter above depicts its usage. Your real session ID can be found in various ways depending on your API wrapper you are using. (*You can also get it from your browser's dev tools in session storage*) But I think that if you are wanting to make a bot for testing something or a quick project you may still use any random string as your sessionID.